# Calling parse function in swift fails

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I am working on a food delivery app, which uses parse as its backend. I am facing a problem while calling the placeOrder API through

`PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: PlaceOrder, withParameters: params) { (data, err) in}`

Please have a look at the JSON which I need to post below.

```
{
 "source": "card_1EVYuOEynlyM6L4SHgBMJYRQ",
 "userId": "YjSZYSXEp7",
   "data": {
            "menuItems": [{
                            "id": "QSYa2JDcIm",
                         "title": "Rice With Tibss(Beef)",
                     "menuTitle": "Rice With Tibss",
                   "submenuItem": [{
                                    "id": "zaOo6G4KSV",
                                  "name": "Beef",
                                 "price": 12,
                                  "desc": "Fillings?"
                                   }],
                         "price": 24,
                           "qty": 1,
                       "storeId": "yqBCDmzaDP",
                     "storeName": "Ibex Ethiopian Cusine and Bar",
                     "orderType": "takeout",
                      "taxState": 0.0925,
                     "storeInfo": {
                                   "cart_storeId": "yqBCDmzaDP",
                                 "cart_storeName": "Ibex Ethiopian Cusine and Bar",
                                "cart_storeImage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/http-get-tolofood-com/image/upload/c_scale,h_199,q_auto,w_270/v1461575640/Ibex_lopx38.jpg",
                              "cart_storeCuisine": "Ethiopian",
                          "cart_storeDescription": "We always serve a quality food. We always serve a quality food. We always serve a quality food. We always serve a quality food.",
                               "cart_storeRating": 3.33,
                             "cart_storeDelivery": false,
                                        "takeout": true,
                                        "address": "12255 Greenville Ave,Dallas, TX 75243",
                                       "slugname": "TX_DAL_ibex_ethiopian_cuisine_and_bar",
                              "multiple_location": false,
                          "cart_storeDeliveryFee": 15,
                               "cart_storeServes": "Lunch,Dinner",
                                           "busy": false,
                              "cart_storeSeoSlug": "ibex-ethiopian-cusine-and-bar"
                                  },
                       "enable": true,
          "voice_read_mi_label": "fbgcb",
         "voice_read_mi_option": false,
                 "menuTypeName": "Standard"
                            }],
   "lastOrderType": "takeout",
   "searchedAddress": "takeout",
   "timeData": {
                "day": "06-05-2019",
               "time": "12:55 am",
                 "tz": "America/Los_Angeles"
               }
            },
 "unavailable_option": "restaurant_recommendation"
  }
```

And below is the Swift code which I have used to make pass it.

```
let storeInfo: Dictionary = [CartStoreId: self.cartStoreId, CartStoreName: self.cartRestaurantName, CartStoreImage: self.cartStoreImage, CartStoreCuisine: self.cartStoreCuisine, CartStoreDescription: self.cartStoreDescription, CartStoreRating: self.cartStoreRating, CartStoreDelivery: self.cartStoreDelivery, Takeout: self.takeOut, Address: self.address, Slugname: self.slugName, MultipleLocation: self.multipleLocation, CartStoreDeliveryFee: self.cartStoreDelivery, CartStoreServes: self.cartStoreServes, Busy: self.busy, CartStoreSeoSlug: self.cartStoreSeoSlug] as Dictionary
let subMenuItem = ["id": "zaOo6G4KSV", "name": "Beef", "price": 12, "desc": "Fillings?", "voice_read_submi_label":"bf", "voice_read_submi_option":false, "disabled": false] as [String: Any]
let ordersDictionary = [
            "id" : "1234",
            "title" : "Test",
            "menuTitle" : "MenuName",
            "price" : 23,
            "qty" : 2,
            "storeId" : 23,
            "orderType" : "standard",
            "taxState" : 0.22,
            "enable" : true,
            "menuTypeName" : "Type Name",
            "voice_read_mi_label":"fdfs",
            "voice_read_mi_option":"false",
            "submenuitem": subMenuItem,
            "storeInfo": storeInfo
            ] as Dictionary
let timeData = ["day" : 17-06-2019, "time": "11:00 AM", "tz": "America/Los_Angeles"] as Dictionary
let data = ["menuItems": ordersDictionary, "lastOrderType": "takeout", "searchedAddress": "takeout", "timeData" : timeData] as Dictionary
let params = [UserId: self.userId, "source":"card_1EVYuOEynlyM6L4SHgBMJYRQ", "data": data, "unavailable_option":"restaurant_recommendation","_ApplicationId":"6EuadToYoFGJhI1sX8XnuFBz9tp9l3yH6HxzzXZO", "_JavaScriptKey":"rQkALu9saFtF2oq9yCibyw6mEcs3PVqct3uuP6vg", "_ClientVersion":"js1.6.14", "_InstallationId":"444ec64d-5fcc-7b8e-596e-6be627892c2a",
        "_SessionToken":"r:c966376120c8eca77aa63c29d5bebe1a"] as Dictionary
```

After all this is done I call the parse function like below.

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: PlaceOrder, withParameters: params) { (data, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
        } else {
            print(data!)
        }
    }
```

But this gives me error after a few seconds saying

```
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}"
```

I have searched the web with the error and made fixes accordingly but still no success. Please help me guys.

Comment: If you call with ```PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: PlaceOrder, withParameters: [] as Dictionary)```, does it work? Can you please also paste here how you are initializing the Parse SDK? Are the other API calls you are doing to Parse properly working? If you test your function by calling it using the API console, does it work?

Comment: Other functions and APIs are working fine. SDK is also initialized properly. Only issue is with this API. But this API is working fine for Web App and Android App

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I tried as Dictionary as well. Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your params var is not compatible with the JSON you sent, there are more fields and also missing fields. Moreover, menuItems and submenuItem are an Array in your JSON and an Object in your code. It is probably making the cloud code function to fail and you are therefore not receiving back a valid JSON. Try the following and check if it works. In the case it works, just replace the values by your vars.

```
let params = [
    "source": "card_1EVYuOEynlyM6L4SHgBMJYRQ",
    "userId": "YjSZYSXEp7",
    "data": [
        "menuItems": [[
            "id": "QSYa2JDcIm",
            "title": "Rice With Tibss(Beef)",
            "menuTitle": "Rice With Tibss",
            "submenuItem": [[
                "id": "zaOo6G4KSV",
                "name": "Beef",
                "price": 12,
                "desc": "Fillings?"
            ]],
            "price": 24,
            "qty": 1,
            "storeId": "yqBCDmzaDP",
            "storeName": "Ibex Ethiopian Cusine and Bar",
            "orderType": "takeout",
            "taxState": 0.0925,
            "storeInfo": [
                "cart_storeId": "yqBCDmzaDP",
                "cart_storeName": "Ibex Ethiopian Cusine and Bar",
                "cart_storeImage": "https://res.cloudinary.com/http-get-tolofood-com/image/upload/c_scale,h_199,q_auto,w_270/v1461575640/Ibex_lopx38.jpg",
                "cart_storeCuisine": "Ethiopian",
                "cart_storeDescription": "We always serve a quality food. We always serve a quality food. We always serve a quality food. We always serve a quality food.",
                "cart_storeRating": 3.33,
                "cart_storeDelivery": false,
                "takeout": true,
                "address": "12255 Greenville Ave,Dallas, TX 75243",
                "slugname": "TX_DAL_ibex_ethiopian_cuisine_and_bar",
                "multiple_location": false,
                "cart_storeDeliveryFee": 15,
                "cart_storeServes": "Lunch,Dinner",
                "busy": false,
                "cart_storeSeoSlug": "ibex-ethiopian-cusine-and-bar"
            ],
            "enable": true,
            "voice_read_mi_label": "fbgcb",
            "voice_read_mi_option": false,
            "menuTypeName": "Standard"
        ]],
        "lastOrderType": "takeout",
        "searchedAddress": "takeout",
        "timeData": [
            "day": "06-05-2019",
            "time": "12:55 am",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles"
        ]
    ],
    "unavailable_option": "restaurant_recommendation"
]
```